# jinja2 autoescape extension not working

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a problem with Jinja2 autoescape which drives me mad. According to 
documentation, I do the following

```
import jinja2
env=jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True,extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'])
tpl = jinja_env.template_class('{% autoescape false %}...{% endautoescape %}')
```

However, python throws the following exception:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 906, in __new__
  return env.from_string(source, template_class=cls)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 841, in from_string
  return cls.from_code(self, self.compile(source), globals, None)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 554, in compile
  self.handle_exception(exc_info, source_hint=source)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 742, in handle_exception
  reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "<unknown>", line 1, in template
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'autoescape'.
```

However, when I check the env.extensions dictionary, it *does* contain an
jinja2.ext.AutoEscapeExtension object and this object, has a tag attribute, which
is equal to set(['autoescape']). So everything seems it should be working, but it does not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I didn't read the documentation... I shouldn't have been using `env.template_class` to get the template but `env.from_string`. Stupid me...